# Why do we use #{} for interpolation? Can't we just use a scss variable instead?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I've seen the use of #{} in the following:

```
$information-phone: "only screen and (max-width : 320px)";

@media #{$information-phone} {
    background: red;
}
```

What's the purpose of using #{}? Couldn't I simply do the following:

```
$information-phone: "only screen and (max-width : 320px)";

@media $information-phone {
    background: red;
}
```

Essentially, couldn't I use a sass variable wherever interpolation (#{}) is used?

Answer (score 0):

I think because Sass is processed by Ruby and  in Ruby the "printing" of variables values is managed by the interpolation #{myVar}

[Ruby Interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)